# Can we download music by Stream link in Android

Tags: android, stream, download

I am developing an online music android application and i need download some music on a third party server but they only give me stream links so i am finding a way to download music by stream link only.

My friend's working at iOS and he can do it in iOS by merge the stream packages to a music file.

Comment: What server are you using? :D I wanna know, too! :D

Comment: haha, this is souncloud :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to play and download the .mp3 file from any url then follow the code suggested.

But if you want to download a file form the server and store it in any place on sdcard or internal storage device then follow this code,

```
private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            int count;
            try {
                URL url = new URL("url of your .mp3 file");
                URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
                conexion.connect();
                // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100% progress bar
                int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();

                // downlod the file
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/somewhere/nameofthefile.mp3");

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    publishProgress((int)(total*100/lenghtOfFile));
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {}
            return null;
        }
```

EDIT: manifest permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. i can download it. :D